# In Perl source code, where can I find the implementation of the sort routine?

Tags: perl

I would like to experiment with Perl by modifying the actual sort routine.
I did `grep` over the source trying to find some files with name patterns mentioning **`sort`**, yet did not find anything relevant.

Could anyone of you tell in what file the sort implementation resides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find out the opcodes generated by your code using B::Concise:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise -e'sort'
5  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{ ->3
4     <@> sort vK ->5
3        <0> pushmark s ->4
-e syntax OK
```

The name of the opcode for the `sort` operator is `sort`. (This is obviously most useful when the name of the opcode isn't the same as the name of the operator; for example, the opcode for the scalar assignment operator `=` is `sassign`.)

The opcodes are implemented in various .c files at the top level of the Perl source directory. The definition of opcode `foo` usually* looks like this:

```
PP(pp_foo) {
    // implementation
}
```

So:

```
grep pp_sort /path/to/perl/source/*.c
```

In this case, the `sort` opcode actually lives in its own file: [`pp_sort.c`](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/cc93400aa5a8d556c56c28a8de644bd178d050d4/pp_sort.c).

---

* There are a few exceptions. For example, the `keys` opcode is actually implemented in `Perl_do_kv`, as indicated by this line in opcode.h:

```
#define Perl_pp_keys Perl_do_kv
```

If you can't find `pp_foo` for a given opcode, check opcode.h.

Comment: *Teach a man how to sort, and they'll sort themselves out - Apocryphal*

Answer (score 4):

If you're planning on modifying Perl's internals, you need to know a considerable amount about how Perl works internally. Start by reading the `perlhack` manpage, and follow its pointers to several more (quite long!) manual pages.

Comment: Thanks! Will take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I went to https://github.com/Perl/perl5/search?q=sort.

The first search hit was `sort.pm`, which looked like a good hint. Since that module does not define the search itself, I looked there for keywords that would help me along the way. I chose `_quicksort` and `_mergesort`.

https://github.com/Perl/perl5/search?q=_quicksort didn’t show any relevant results, so I tried just `quicksort`.

That gave me `pp_sort.c`, and there you go. Almost 2000 lines full of sorting.